# How to find a min/max with Ruby

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I want to use `min(5,10)`, or `Math.max(4,7)`.  Are there functions to this effect in Ruby?

Answer (score 835, accepted):

#### `.min`

```rb
[5, 10].min
```

#### `.max`

```rb
[4, 7].max
```

They come from the [Enumerable module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html), so anything that includes `Enumerable` will have those methods available.

v2.4 introduces own `Array#min` and `Array#max`, which are way faster than Enumerable's methods because they skip calling `#each`.

#### `.minmax`

@nicholasklick mentions another option, [`Enumerable#minmax`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax), but this time returning an array of `[min, max]`.

```rb
[4, 5, 7, 10].minmax
#=> [4, 10]
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize the array first by removing nil values, or values that cannot be compared

Comment: Ruby is mainly for the programmer not for the computer. In Matz's words "I hope to see Ruby help every programmer in the world to be productive, and to enjoy programming, and to be happy. That is the primary purpose of Ruby language." That's from the Wikipedia page on Ruby.

Comment: @aaron-coding Well, helping the programmer to write inefficient code isn't exactly helping him. ;) But yes - I know in _many_ cases these micro-optimizations don't matter. However, I think there is an underlying problem in Ruby encouraging inefficiency. Efficiency is not Ruby's greatest strength or design goal; it has other, more eloquent values.

Comment: Am I wrong, or does @nicholasklick not exist any more? I wanted to link him, but weren't able to find him.

Comment: The existence of `.minmax` is yet another reason why I love Ruby.

Answer (score 59):

You can use

```
[5,10].min
```

or

```
[4,7].max
```

It's a method for Arrays.

Comment: Technically it's a method for Enumerables, not Arrays.

Comment: It's a method for Arrays with superior performance over Enumerable's since v2.4

Answer (score 32):

If you need to find the max/min of a hash, you can use `#max_by` or `#min_by`

```
people = {'joe' => 21, 'bill' => 35, 'sally' => 24}

people.min_by { |name, age| age } #=> ["joe", 21]
people.max_by { |name, age| age } #=> ["bill", 35]
```

Answer (score 32):

All those results generate garbage in a zealous attempt to handle more than two arguments. I'd be curious to see how they perform compared to good 'ol:

```
def max (a,b)
  a>b ? a : b
end
```

which is, by-the-way, my official answer to your question.

Comment: There's some rumblings that Ruby 2.4 is optimizing `[a,b].max`, but it's still not clear if it's faster than the above implementation. 
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/17/ruby-2-4-implements-array-min-and-max.html

Comment: this is micro-optimization, they're both so fast, the difference is negligible, see benchmark: https://repl.it/@AndreFigueiredo/DearWeirdSweepsoftware

Comment: Does this profiling take into account the time spent in GC?

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the provided answers, if you want to convert [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) into a max method that can call a variable number or arguments, like in some other programming languages, you could write:

```
def max(*values)
 values.max
end
```

Output:

```
max(7, 1234, 9, -78, 156)
=> 1234
```

This abuses the properties of the splat operator to create an array object containing all the arguments provided, or an empty array object if no arguments were provided. In the latter case, the method will return `nil`, since calling [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) on an empty array object returns `nil`.

If you want to define this method on the Math module, this should do the trick:

```
module Math
 def self.max(*values)
  values.max
 end
end
```

Note that Enumerable.max is, at least, [two times slower compared to the ternary operator (`?:`)](http://codepad.org/4uhWD7Yj). See [Dave Morse's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34709673/3996083) for a simpler and faster method.

Comment: But isn't reopening standard classes and modules considered a bad practice?

Comment: You could do a monkey patch only locally with the `module` keyword.